# How to get the full path of a particular directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have got a directory /home/usr/AAA and I stored some file and folders there

```
/home/usr/AAA/Mark/15456/sdfsd/VIP_Info_sdfsdf
/home/usr/AAA/Jack/23678/gwewd/VIP_Info_wetwod
...
```

I can use some bash script like

```
cd /home/usr/AAA     
find -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 4 -type d -iname "VIP_Info*" -printf '%f\n'
```

returning

```
VIP_Info_sdfsdf
VIP_Info_wetwod
```

to get the particular folder name I am interested in, ie, the ones started with VIP_Info.

However, I want to go into each folder and do some operation.

May I ask how to get the full path of each folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$PWD` and the `%P` format instead:

```
find -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 4 -type d -iname "VIP_Info*" -printf "$PWD/%P\n"
```

Alternatively, use `%p` and pass the full name of the current directory to `find`, rather than letting it default to the working directory.

```
find /home/usr/AAA -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 4 -type d -iname "VIP_Info*" -printf "%p\n"
```

Note that `-print` and `-printf "%p\n"` are equivalent.

Since you aren't using any other of the filters that `find` provides and you seem to know the depth of the directories you are looking for, you can simply use a glob pattern without involving `find`:

```
printf "%s\n" /home/usr/AAA/*/*/*/VIP_Info*/
```

Comment: The first method seems not quite right. I tested and it returns $PWD/Mark/15456/sdfsd/VIP_Info_sdfsdf, but not the full path /home/usr/AAA/Mark/15456/sdfsd/VIP_Info_sdfsdf

Comment: D'oh. I tested with double quotes, but used single quotes in the post for some reason. I'll fix.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that guy delete his post, but this is a good solution:

```
find `pwd` -type d -iname "VIP_Info*"
```

Just for other people's reference.